# How to use Dynamic Maps Javascript API without Street View?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

how can i use only Dynamic Maps with Maps Javascript API without Dynamic Street View like here in the description:
https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#dynamic-maps

i use maps like this:

```
const eventMapOptions = {
               panControl: false,
                zoomControl: true,
                scaleControl: true,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                center: ...,
               zoom: 16,
               streetViewControl: false
};

new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map', eventMapOptions);
```

now i have for example for the last month:

14479 maps loads - Maps JavaScript API

14479 maps loads - Maps and Street View API

i don't want and don't use street view api and have to pay for this

but how can i disable usage of street view?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.streetViewControl

Answer (score 0):

In the [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions) set `streetViewControl` to `false` and the feature will disappear.

#### Example

```js
var mapOptions =
{
    streetViewControl: false,

    // ...
};
```

#### Documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions